# Solve $\tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta) = \tan (3\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the general solution of:
>   $$\tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta) = \tan (3\theta)$$

My Attempt:
$$\tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta) = \tan (3\theta)$$
$$\dfrac {\sin (\theta)}{\cos (\theta)}+ \dfrac {\sin (2\theta)}{\cos (2\theta)}=\dfrac {\sin (3\theta)}{\cos (3\theta)}$$
$$\dfrac {\sin (\theta+2\theta)}{\cos (\theta) \cos (2\theta)}=\dfrac {\sin (3\theta)}{\cos (3\theta)}$$

Comment: by general solution, you mean what is $\theta$?

Comment: Theta = n*pi We can convert tan 2theta and tan 3theta into tan theta by conversion formulae, and after simplifying we will get our answer as theta= n*pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta) &= \tan(3\theta) \\
   \tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta) &= \tan(\theta + 2\theta) \\
   \dfrac{\tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta)}{1}
      &= \dfrac{\tan(\theta) + \tan(2\theta)}
               {1-\tan (\theta) \tan (2\theta)} \\
\end{align}

So, either $\tan (\theta) + \tan (2\theta)=0$, or 
           $\tan (\theta) = 0$, or $\tan (2\theta)=0$

\begin{align}
   \tan(\theta) + \tan(2\theta) &= 0 \\
   \tan(\theta) + \dfrac{2 \tan(\theta)}{1 - \tan^2(\theta)} &= 0 \\
   3 \tan(\theta) - \tan^3(\theta) &= 0 \\
   \tan(\theta) &\in \{0, \pm \sqrt 3\}
\end{align}

So $\theta \in \left\{
   n\pi, \pm\frac 13\pi + n\pi, \pm\frac 14\pi + n\pi 
   : n \in \mathbb Z
   \right\}$

Comment: $$\tan2\theta=\tan(-\theta)\implies2\theta=n\pi-\theta$$ But what if $\tan2\theta=0$ and $\tan\theta\ne0?$

Comment: Since  $\tan(2\theta)=\dfrac{2 \tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}$, then that can't happen.

Comment: What if $\theta=n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: Then $\tan \theta = \infty$

Comment: and $$\tan2\theta=?$$

Comment: And $\tan(\theta) + \tan(2 \theta) = ?$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75684/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-steven-gregory).

Comment: Nice answer, but I think $\pm\frac14\pi+n\pi$ shouldn't be included since $\tan 2\theta$ will be undefined in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Check if one of $\cos\theta,\cos2\theta,\cos3\theta=0$

Else we have $$\sin3\theta(\cos3\theta-\cos\theta\cos2\theta)=0$$

What if $\sin3\theta=0?$

Else use $$2\cos\theta\cos2\theta=\cos3\theta+\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a hint to get you started which is that $\text{tan}(a + b) = \dfrac{\text{tan}(a) + \text{tan}(b)}{1-\text{tan}(a)\text{tan}(b)}$.

Comment: @ user2888499, what formula is that?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... Sorry I had a typo that has been fixed. It's the tangent addition formula.

Comment: Whatever the correct formula may  be that is clearly wrong.

Comment: @martycohen I don't see how this is wrong. I have checked it again for any errors.

Comment: @martycohen The only mistake I see is typesetting "tan" as `\text{tan}` instead of just `\tan`. The math is correct.